# ng-repeat how to handle a button element separately

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to populate data in a table so far so good. What i am trying to accomplish is to use a button and change it's text according to the userId (cust.id). I am trying to understand how to use a $scope inside a repeat method and modify it separately from the other elements.

On the following demo when i click to button with (userid value = 1) then i would like to change the specific button text and NOT every button in my ng-repeat

```
<button ng-click="perLineText(cust.id)">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfonsos/c9q7vx1j/)

I am trying to figure out how to handle specific elements in my ng-repeat. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by just using the `this` in you controller function instead of `$scope`.

```
$scope.perLineText = function(customerId){
   if (customerId === 1) {
     this.buttonText = 'Stop';
   };
```

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u5swjwv1/

On a click callback `this` points to the scope of nested repeat element. If you use `$scope` you are actually referring to the parent scope object.

Look at this explanation too ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: Chandermani, can you please help me on this one also...i am trying to use $interval and use a counter for each row separately...i tried to use 'this' instead of '$scope' but no luck. Here is the code... [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfonsos/uthuzqnm/4/) thank you for your time!

Comment: I am not sure what you scenario is. Is there a interval for each button or a common one. What is the scenario?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to have an interval for each button separately. Each start button is attached to each line separately, the same with the stop button also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle this problem is using `$index`. Just pass it when calling your `perLineText($index)` function so you know which row you are in. Now you can simply work with the appropriate index object in your array which might my `$scope.customers[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ng-bind="perLineText(cust.id)" instead of the {{buttonText}} so the ng-click will toogle something and the perLineText will return Start or Stop.